# Codename One - Is there a way to avoid changing Button's UIID on click?

Tags: codenameone

Here is code example to face my problem.

```
Container master, content;
Button lockButton;
void layout () {
    master = new Container (new LayeredLayout ());
    content = new Container (BoxLayout.y());
    content.setScrollableY (true);
    lockButton = new Button ("");
    lockButton.setUIID ("ButtonInvisible");
    lockButton.addActionListener ((e)->{
        unlock ();
    });
    master.add(content);
}
void lock () {
    master.add(lockButton);
}
void unlock () {
    lockButton.remove ();
}
```

ButtonInvisible *selected*, *unselected* and *pressed* styles are equal.

Problem description:

1. Scroll `content` down
2. Invoke `lock()`
3. Click on `content` (`lockButton` intercepts click)
4. While pointer is pressed `content`'s scrolling is 0, on release it returns to previous amount.

I guess this happens because Button changes it's Style on click, which causes repainting/revalidating bug of underlying content.

**Update according to Diamond's answer**

*Additional information*:

Container `master` is center part of `SwipeableContainer`.

Method `lock()` is invoked whenever `SwipeableContainer` is opened.

If I invoke `revalidate()` when `SwipeableContainer` is open - screen strangely flickers, but behavior is not changed - whenever Button is pressed scrolling still jumps to zero.

Maybe it is significant - there is `Tabs` component in container `content`

In this version of code revalidation can not be a reason for such problem, because no components is added or removed, but the problem is still the same.

```
Container master, content;
Button lockButton;
void layout () {
    master = new Container (new LayeredLayout ());
    content = new Container (BoxLayout.y());
    content.setScrollableY (true);
    lockButton = new Button ("");
    lockButton.setUIID ("ButtonInvisible");
    lockButton.addActionListener ((e)->{
        unlock ();
    });
    lockButton.setFocusable(false);
    master.add(content).add(lockButton);
}
void lock () {
    lockButton.setFocusable(true);
}
void unlock () {
    swipeableContainer.close ();
    lockButton.setFocusable(false);
}
```

Comment: I find the problem really hard to understand from the description. But here are a few things I can say. Buttons don't change UIID's. Style changes don't revalidate or impact scrolling. A couple of screenshots or a video can go a long way to explain what happned

Comment: Thanks for your attention, I will provide video as fast as I can.

Comment: This thing happens only in simulator, on devices everything is perfect. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when you invoked `lock()` revalidation didn't occur, thereby `lockButton` wasn't correctly laid out, it's only properly positioned when you click on any part of the `master` container (scrolling doesn't apply).

The solution is to always call `repaint()`/`revalidate()` or some sort of animations after major UI changes like addition and removal of components to/from a container.

```
Container master, content;
Button lockButton;
void layout () {
    master = new Container (new LayeredLayout ());
    content = new Container (BoxLayout.y());
    content.setScrollableY (true);
    lockButton = new Button ("");
    lockButton.setUIID ("ButtonInvisible");
    lockButton.addActionListener ((e)->{
        unlock ();
    });
    master.add(content);
    master.revalidate();
}
void lock () {
    master.add(lockButton);
    master.revalidate();
}
void unlock () {
    lockButton.remove();
    master.revalidate();
}
```

Comment: Please check my changes.

Answer (score 0):

This happens only in Simulator. On real device everything is OK. Sorry.